# How to get more than one smallest /largest values of a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, dictionary

Like if i create a dictionary using the following script:

```
r_lst = {}
for z in df.index:
  t = x.loc[0, 'sn']
  s = df.loc[z, 'rv']
  slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(t,s)
  r_lst.setdefault(float(z),[]).append(float(r_value))
```

The resultant dictionary loos like this

```
{4050.32: [0.29174641574734467],
 4208.98: [0.20938901991887324],
 4374.94: [0.2812420188097632],
 4379.74: [0.28958742731611586],
 4398.01: [0.3309140298947313],
 4502.21: [0.28702220304639836],
 4508.28: [0.2170363811575936],
 4512.99: [0.29080133884942105]}
```

Now if i want to find the smallest or largest values of the dictionary then i just have to use this simple command `min(r_lst.values())` or `max(r_lst.values())`.

What if i want the three lowest values or three highest values.? Then how can i get that? I saw some questions here but none of them answers what i'm asking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `sorted()`:

```
sorted(r_lst.values())
```

Or in reverse order:

```
sorted(r_lst.values(), reverse=True)
```

So to get the 3 largest values:

```
sorted(r_lst.values(), reverse=True)[:3]
```

Yields:

```
[[0.3309140298947313], [0.29174641574734467], [0.29080133884942105]]
```

Comment: what if i want the keys of those values as well?How can i get that?

Comment: Dictionaries are not intended to be used in that manner. A specific value could be associated with multiple keys.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`heapq.nsmallest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.nsmallest) / [`heapq.nlargest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest):

```
import heapq

res = heapq.nsmallest(3, d.values())

# [[0.20938901991887324], [0.2170363811575936], [0.2812420188097632]]
```

To extract as a flat list, you can use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
from itertools import chain
import heapq

res = list(chain.from_iterable(heapq.nsmallest(3, d.values())))

# [0.20938901991887324, 0.2170363811575936, 0.2812420188097632]
```

These `heapq` solutions will have time complexity O((*n*-*k*)*log *n*) versus O(*n* log *n*) for solutions requiring a full sort.

Comment: I knew about this function but it didn't works on a dictionary.